# How to properly update state of component after promise inside promise call?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function

```
fetch(fileUrl)
            .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
            .then(blob => {
                const file = new File([blob], this.props.name, {
                    type: "text/plain",
                });

               reader.loadFile(file)
                    .then((response) =>  {
                        reader.getLines(1, response.result.lineCount, true)
                            .then((response) => {
                                this.setState({
                                    content: response.result
                                });
                                return result = response.result;
                                //here result is filled

                            })
                            .catch((reason)  => {
                                console.log(reason)
                            });
                        console.log(this.state)
                    })
                    .catch( (reason): void => {
                        console.log(reason);
                    }); 
           //here result is empty if console.log
            })
```

I call it inside render of the component, and I want to display `content` from the state in this component as well. The problem is that the state is empty on the first click to display my component, and then fills up on the second click.

`response.result` is an array

I also have `shouldComponentUpdate` in my component which may be causing this issue. I'm not sure how to compare two arrays in the right way there. Because if I compare them just vie `!==` update runs all the time.

Comment: try async function await

Comment: @NijatAliyev I think I made it work by setting in shouldComponentUpdate comparison for my array by length. Not sure if it is the right way to compare two arrays though

Answer (score 0):

```
// First, separate your logic into an async function
const getContent = async (fileUrl, reader, name) => {
  const blob = await fetch(fileUrl).then(res => res.blob());
  const file = new File([blob], name, { type: "text/plain" });
  const response = await reader.loadFile(file);
  const content = await reader.getLines(1, response.result.lineCount, true);
  return content;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  // Call your async function to set state
  async getFile() {
    try {
      const { fileUrl, reader, name } = this.props;
      const content = await getContent(fileUrl, reader, name);
      this.setState({ content });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  // Dummy render function :)
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.getFile.bind(this)}>
        Click me to read the file
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can wait for the result by wrap the fetch method in a promise function. Here is I think might work:

```
myFunction = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    try {
      fetch(fileUrl)
        .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
        .then(blob => {
          const file = new File([blob], this.props.name, {
            type: "text/plain",
          });

          reader.loadFile(file)
            .then((response) => {
              reader.getLines(1, response.result.lineCount, true)
                .then((response) => {
                  return resolve(response.result);
                })
                .catch((reason) => {
                  console.log(reason)
                });
              console.log(this.state)
            })
            .catch((reason): void => {
              console.log(reason);
            });
        })
    } catch (e) {
      // do something here
    }
  })

  callerFunction = async () => {
    try {
      const content = await this.myFunction();
      this.setState({
        content
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // do something here
    }
  }
```